# Bind JSON object as radio data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to solve bind problem in my application. Similar questions are exists on Stackoverflow, but they do not fully describes my scenario.

I have an radio group created using repeater. Each `style` value is the Object so I'm using `ng-value` directive to bind them correct

```
        <label ng-repeat="style in styles">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.style" ng-value="style">
            {{style.name}}
        </label>
```

And my controller logic is very simple:

```
var first = {
   name: "First Name",
   value: "First Value"
};

var second = {
   name: "Second Name",
   value: "Second Value"
};

var third = {
   name: "Third Name",
   value: "Third Value"
};

$scope.styles = [first, second, third];

$scope.formData = {};

//this code works and my screen shows 'second' as selected option
$scope.formData.style = second; 

//this code do not works and my screen do not show 'Second name' as selected
//$scope.formData.style = { 
//       name: "Second Name",
//       value: "Second Value"
//    };
```

This code works as expected. I'm setting my selection and form shows selected option.

But in my particular example I don't have reference to my `second` value and I need to take this data from third control, so my updated code will looks like:

```
$scope.formData.style = {
   name: "Second Name",
   value: "Second Value"
};
```

And this behavior do not works - I do not see radio selection on my screen.

Here is my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/vadimb/L7uw3oos/3/

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I've updated code

Comment: you are initially setting your model `$scope.formData.style` to an anonymous object which just happens to have the same properties with the same values, but your radio buttons aren't bound to the properties, they are bound to the *specific object instances*.

Comment: Like Claies has said, the reason here is because you are binding the radio button to the **exact property** on your model `$scope.formData.style` which in the first example is set to `second` which is an item within your `$scope.styles` array (which you are iterating over to display your radio buttons).

You are not binding it to the correct object that is in the `$scope.styles` array, the items within `$scope.styles` are their own objects, when you are writing `$scope.formData.style = { ... }` you are creating a **brand new object**

Comment: I can make this code works even with brand new object for combobox, but not for radio. So seems the problem not in this place - re-creating object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason here is because you are binding the radio button to the **exact property** on your model `$scope.formData.style` which in the first example is set to `second` which is an item within your `$scope.styles` array.

When you bind your radio button to a *new* object:

```
$scope.formData.style = {
    name: "Second Name",
    value: "Second Value"
};
```

You are not binding it to the object that is in the `$scope.styles` array, `$scope.formData.style` is now it's own completely separate object.

If you want to set it dynamically, you must lookup the item you want from within `$scope.styles`.

### Using Underscore:

`$scope.formData.style = _.findWhere($scope.styles, { name: "Second Name"})`

### Using Pure JS:

```
function getFromArray(array, value) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].name.toLowerCase() == value.toLowerCase()) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
}

$scope.formData.style = getFromArray($scope.styles, "Second Name");
```

Although I'd recommend using some sort of Id instead of a magic string.

Comment: Unfortunately I can iterate through this array, I need something like `track by` for `ng-value` directive. Anyway thanks for your attention.

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you unable to iterate through the array?